# Top 10 for each Country on Business Objects Webi

Tags: business-objects, webix

I am basically trying to get the top 10 claims by order of fee for all countries. The ranking is simple to do and i already have the rank built.

`=Rank([Estimated Loss Amount Home Currency];([Claim ID]);Top)`

But how do i apply that so it does the top 10 for each country? 
At the moment i have it set up with a break on the country so it ranks the claims within each country. So for example Australia has 21 claims showing (which is all of them and ranks them 1 - 21). When I apply my rank variable as a filter for the top 10, it does it on my whole data set not each country so i end up with top 10 in just Australia and lose the rest of the countries.

I have recreated it in SQL which is easy to do, just cant fathom the logic round it in Webi.

Thank you.

Comment: http://vhgropb1sbo01.stl.hec.growmark.com:8080/BOE/portal/1606021644/AnalyticalReporting/help/en/frameset.htm?471ca7b46e041014910aba7db0e91070.html

Answer (score 0):

The [technical documentation](http://vhgropb1sbo01.stl.hec.growmark.com:8080/BOE/portal/1606021644/AnalyticalReporting/help/en/frameset.htm?471ca7b46e041014910aba7db0e91070.html) indicates how to do this:  Most of the below is a direct copy from that technical documentation.

**Syntax**

```
int Rank(measure;[ranking_dims][;Top|Bottom][;(reset_dims)])
```

**Input**

```
+--------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+
|  Parameter   |               Description               |      Type      |      Required       |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| measure      | The measure to be ranked                | Measure        | Yes                 |
| ranking_dims | The dimensions used to rank the measure | Dimension list | No                  |
| Top|Bottom   | Sets the ranking order:                 | Keyword        | No (Top is default) |
|              |                                         |                |                     |
|              | Top - descending                        |                |                     |
|              | Bottom - ascending                      |                |                     |
|              |                                         |                |                     |
| reset_dims   | The dimensions that reset the ranking   | Dimension list | No                  |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

**Notes**

- The function uses the default calculation context to calculate the ranking if you do not specify ranking dimensions.
- You must always place dimensions in parentheses even if there is only one dimension in the list of ranking or reset dimensions.
- When you specify a set of ranking or reset dimensions you must separate them with semi-colons.
- By default the ranking is reset over a section or block break.

**So in your case:**

```
=Rank([Estimated Loss Amount Home Currency];([Claim ID]);Top;([Country]))
```

**Example**
In the following table the rank is given by `Rank([Revenue];([Country];[Year]);([Country]))`. The rank is reset on the Country dimension.

```
+---------+--------+---------+------+
| Country |  Year  | Revenue | Rank |
+---------+--------+---------+------+
| France  | FY1998 | 295,940 |    1 |
| France  | FY1999 | 280,310 |    2 |
| France  | FY2000 | 259,170 |    3 |
| US      | FY1998 | 767,614 |    3 |
| US      | FY1999 | 826,930 |    2 |
| US      | FY2000 | 856,560 |    1 |
+---------+--------+---------+------+
```